# What type hint to use in python for a class variable of an abstract base class that is to become instantiated with a subclass

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to use [this pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm) for a singleton dataclass that is also an abstract base class, with the following code:

```
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import TypeVar, Any


TConfig = TypeVar("TConfig", bound="ConfigBase")


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ConfigBase(ABC):
    """Base class for main Config class"""

    # _instance should have type TConfig, but so far no way to specify that properly
    # Therefore, method get_instance has two times type: ignore in the return statements
    _instance: "ConfigBase" = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls: type[TConfig]) -> TConfig:
        """Access method for the singleton."""
        try:
            return cls._instance  # type: ignore
        except AttributeError as _:
            sections: dict[str, Any] = {}
            # code that initializes sections
            cls(**sections)  # __post_init__ will set _instance
            return cls._instance  # type: ignore

    def __post_init__(self: TConfig) -> None:
        """Virtually private constructor."""
        type(self)._instance = self
```

What type hint to use for `_instance` such that mypy will not complain when I remove the two `# type: ignore`s?

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html before deciding if this is something you want to spend time on.

Comment: why not just have it return *object*? This fixes the mypy issue. Change the _instance line to `_instance: object = field(init=False, repr=False)` and change the function header to `def get_instance(cls: type[TConfig]) -> object:`

Comment: `_instance: Self` should be the working solution, but `mypy` [doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11871).

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the pointer, that was a useful read. It means that my use-case may not be the best. Yet I would like to know how to provide a type hint in this situation

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum thank you for the response. The type hint _object_ defeats the whole purpose of typing, so that is not what I am after.

Comment: @SUTerliakov indeed Self seems to be the solution. The PEP introducing Self: [link](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) suggests an equivalent that is usable in eg python 3.9 that I try to use. But I do not know how to bind it to the class.

Comment: @TheodeVries Unfortunately, no way, it's "strict" equivalent is classproperty, which involves metaclasses (cannot be implemented with descriptors since you need a setter), and I'm sure that metaclass' `__setattr__` cannot help `mypy` (even `__getattr__` on class itself doesn't satisfy mypy completely). Here's [the best I can think of](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1a3eb9856b72add48014e8afab3cc916)